# Having trouble centering svg text path with CSS on Desktop

Tags: css, svg

I have looked at the other svg text questions but I am having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong. I am working on a live site https://sourdoughstory.com/product/mushroom/
and using the code

```html
<svg class="svg-width desktop" style="margin:auto">
    <path id="curve-individual-desktop" d="M 50 170 q 185 -70 400 0" />
    <text>
        <textPath xlink:href="#curve-individual-desktop" class="color-text" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
        Thoughtfully Sourced
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

I am able to center it on mobile but between the screen sizes of 1000px and 1350px it is skewed and I can't seem to figure out how to center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `viewBox` attribute and add some css.
Try to play with the values to get the desired output:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-width desktop" viewBox="50 100 400 70">
  <path id="curve-individual-desktop" d="M 50 170 q 185 -70 400 0" />
  <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#curve-individual-desktop" class="color-text" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
    Thoughtfully Sourced
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me viewBox! That helped so much